# Function to append text to end not working properly

Tags: javascript

The following code works. However, it shows the "newtext" and then it simply disappears.

Can someone please let me know why it is not staying?

Google Chrome is what I am using to test with.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function addtext() {
        var newtext = "\nThis is the new text";
        document.myforms.test1.value += newtext;
    }
</script>
<form name="myforms">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="20" id="test1">
    line one
    line two
    line three
    line four
    line five</textarea>
    <button onclick="addtext()">Click Me! to</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I just finally got around to looking at this. And HOW in the world is this the same as what you say it is? I looked at that other thread, and it is NOT the same. Please, explain to me how you come to the conclusion that this is a duplicate of that one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `button` tag has the `type=submit` by default so your page will be refreshed after the click and the `textarea` value will be reseted to the default value, you should add `type=button` to avoid that  :

```
<button type="button" onclick="addtext()">Click Me! to</button>
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function addtext() {
  var newtext = "\nThis is the new text";
  document.myforms.test1.value += newtext;
}
```

```html
<form name="myforms">
<textarea rows="10" cols="20" id="test1">
line one
line two
line three
line four
line five</textarea>
<button type='button' onclick="addtext()">Click Me! to</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Good solution!  You could also place the button outside the form, so it doesn't act as a submit button by default.

Comment: Thanks @freginold for your intervention, yes your solution will work too..

Comment: I really wish i could remember what I used this for?